# Unpacking tuple values from mixed list

Tags: python

Imagine I have the following list

```
lst = [("key1", "2"), ("key3", "4"), "somestring", 12345]
```

And I'd like to build a dict out of it (using a dictcomp, that is):

```
d = {key: value 
     for item in lst 
     for key, value in [item]
     if isinstance(item, tuple)}
```

This will blow up with a `ValueError` (too many values to unpack).
When is the `if` clause being evaluated (which is crucial for the unpacking, of course) ?
Note: I know I could use a `filter/lambda` before but wanted to know if it's possible in one step.

Comment: Move the if up one level

Comment: `for key, value in item`, do not put `item` in square bracket!

Comment: Wouldn't the `filter` be cleaner, e.g.: `dict(filter(lambda item: isinstance(item, tuple), lst))`, or just a generator function `dict(item for item in lst if isinstance(item, tuple))`

Comment: @adrtam that won't work. But making a pointless list is pretty ugly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Put it as an answer, it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is what you are looking for :

```
>>> lst = [("key1", "2"), ("key3", "4"), "somestring", 12345]
>>> dict([i for i in lst if type(i) is tuple])
{'key1': '2', 'key3': '4'}
```

Comment: It's idiomatic to use `isinstance(i, tuple)` instead of `type(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following dictcomp:

```
{i[0]: i[1] for i in lst if isinstance(i, tuple)}
# {'key1': '2', 'key3': '4'}
```